# How to merge the rows of a second table into 1 field

Tags: mysql, sql

I've been trying to produce a query that will search table1, and then CONCAT the all the values of  table2.column1 where table1.id = table2.owner

```
People
 name | id
-------------
 tim  | 1
 jill | 2
 john | 3


Dogs
name | owner
--------------
 a   | 1
 b   | 1
 c   | 2
 d   | 2
```

Using the following table i need a query that would output

```
 name | dogs
 -----------
 tim  | a, b
 jill | c, d
 john | NULL (or a blank text or just so long as the name john still shows)
```

I have spent a few hours and really cant do it. Some form of mash between OUTER JOIN, and group_concat(), i think. But i didnt really get close to my answer.

Thank you for all help!

Comment: why doesn't `outer join` worked with you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will want to use **[`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)** and a `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT p.name, GROUP_CONCAT(d.name)
FROM   people p
LEFT JOIN dogs d 
     ON p.id = d.owner
GROUP BY p.name
```

see [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/63a11/1)

Comment: added link for `GROUP_CONCAT` :D

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately we now have the same answer even though yours was originally an INNER JOIN

Comment: Thankyou very much both of you, my problem for hours, solved in minutes:P

Comment: Stackoverflow needs some blinking text tag so that no one could miss that huge "SQL Fiddle with Demo" label

Comment: @zerkms I agree. I used to make it smaller but it seemed like people didn't see it so I decided to go with the flow and make it BIG!!!

Comment: @bluefeet: I bet that usually what newbies only see is some codez to copy-paste ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I guess you looking for **[GROUP_CONCAT](http://mahmudahsan.wordpress.com/2008/08/27/mysql-the-group_concat-function/)** in `MySQL`.

```
SELECT  a.name, GROUP_CONCAT(b.name) dogsName
FROM    People a
        LEFT JOIN Dogs b
          ON a.id = b.owner
GROUP BY a.name
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/73c02/2)